# Cloud dataflow failing with error Cannot process data in separate locations

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

We have a Datafow job that runs overnight. This morning we started getting the following error

S15: (8f3433d5b073b96f): Workflow failed. Causes: (8f3433d5b073b09c): BigQuery import job "******" failed. Causes: (8f3433d5b073b7c9): BigQuery job "**********" in project "******" finished with error(s): job error: Cannot process data in separate locations, error: Cannot process data in separate locations

Is there anyway of finding more details about this error?
We are running GA 1.0.0

Comment: I just retried and it completed successfully.

Comment: Can you provide your job ids so we (bigquery engineers) can look up why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that BigQuery recently added some stricter checks on data location when loading data from a non-US-based GCS bucket or exporting to a non-US-based GCS bucket.

Most of the cases we're seeing today are where a user with an Asia-based GCS bucket is loading data to a US-based bigquery table.

We're in the process of relaxing these restrictions. Please add a comment to this thread if you continue to see this error after 11:30 AM PST on 2015-08-20.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I haven't seen it pop it up again. It appears to be fixed.